# Why does the equality of ranks of the two lie groups $G$ and $H$ insures that the function $f$ do not vanish?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

Let G be a connected compact Lie group, and H a connected Lie subgroup of G such that G and H have the same rank. We denote by $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ the respective Lie algebras.

Consider the map $ ad: \mathfrak{h} \rightarrow End(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h})$ to be the restricted  adjoint representation.  We define the function  $f$ by $f(Y)= det_{\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}}(ad(Y))$ , $Y \in \mathfrak{h}.$

In the article of equivariant cohomology with generalized coefficients, the authors say that the equality of the ranks implies that the function $f$ does not vanish. Why this is true ?

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality of ranks means that if $T\subset H$ is a maximal torus then $T$ is maximal also in $G$. The adjoint representation of $\mathfrak t$ (or of $T$) on $\mathfrak g / \mathfrak t$ has only non-zero weights (the weights are exactly the roots of $\mathfrak g$), hence the same is true for its quotient
$\mathfrak g / \mathfrak h = (\mathfrak g / \mathfrak t) / (\mathfrak h / \mathfrak t)$. Since every element of $\mathfrak h$ is conjugate to an element of $\mathfrak t$ (by the maximality of $T$), you get your statement (the det is the product of the weights applied to the element of $\mathfrak t$).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I have Just one question : I don't understand how to use the argument that every element of $\mathfrak{h}$ is conjugate to an element of $\mathfrak{t}$ to finish the proof, could you please elaborate more in this ?

Comment: @asma the argument showed that $f(Y) \neq0$ for $Y\in\mathfrak t$, then one needs to use that $f$ is ad-invariant

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help @user8268 , thanks a lot!

Comment: you're most welcome :)